# what is the difference between these selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have found two selectors

```
div p
```

and

```
div>p
```

What is the exact  difference between these two css selectors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The first is "descendant" selector: `p` anywhere inside `div`

```css
div p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Div
  <p>Child</p>
  <aside>
    <p>Grandchild</p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

- The second is "child" selector: `p` directly under `div`

```css
div > p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Div
  <p>Child</p>
  <aside>
    <p>Grandchild</p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`div p` this style will select all the p elements under the div whether the p is inside another div.
The `div>p` will only select the p which are under the div. if there is another div into the same div which has p element as well it will not select that p.

Comment: "If there is another div into the same div which has p element as well it will not select that p." Sure it will, just not picking the same start element. In `<div id="root"><div><p>P</p></div></div>`, `div > p`, `div p`, `div#root p` will all select the `<p>`; `div#root > p` will not select it.

Comment: yeah absolutely right ;)